# How to setup code access security locally Eclipse

Tags: security, eclipse, .net-framework, source-code

Is there any way to secure project source code locally in Eclipse work space. I see there is a good feature for CAS in .Net. In .Net IDE when i open a project its asking for

> windows security credentials to Team foundation server

If i don't enter a valid credentials, project content not loading. Is there anything like that in Eclipse.

Please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Wow, I searched Google for "team foundation server code access security", and this question came up on the first page of results, 13 minutes after it was asked.  How often does Google crawl this site?  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not hundred percent sure what you are asking for. On one hand you talk about setup Eclipse *locally* on the other hand you talk about Team Foundation *Server*.

As far as I see, what you can do with Team Foundation Server is regulating access to the source code repositories (on the server). It controls whether you can copy code from this server to your machine (and if you push back changes onto the server etc.). It's not so much a feature of the IDE but rather one of the version control system.

So, how to realize this access control in your Eclipse projects depends on what version control system you use.

For Subversion/svn there are several ways. A good starting point could be

- [How to setup access control in SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81361/how-to-setup-access-control-in-svn) on StackOverflow
- the book [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/), chapter "Server Administration"

  - [Built-in Authentication and Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.auth) for svnserve or
  - [Authorization Options](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authz) for an Apache based setup.

If you are not administrating your subversion server yourself but rather use trac or a similar software that also integrates wiki and issue tracking etc. (closer match to what Team Foundation Server might include) then you can probably configure the authorisation settings in its interface.

In case you are using another version control system, please adapt your question.

Comment: Hi Zpea, Sorry for my English. I really appreciate your answer. As you said regulating access to the source code repositories using SVN is good option to secure the source code on the server. What im looking is, to secure locally in the eclipse ide. Such that to open the Project source code in eclipse workspace it should ask for credentials if i enter valid credentials then only the project should open and can run the project. I hope its clear now. Please let me know.....  Thank you

Comment: Ah okay, now I understand somewhat better. But from whom do you want to protect the source code? I guess the developer working is trusted and would have the password to unlock anyway. Protection against outsiders is usually done on a more general basis (and for more than just the source code): strong password for the user account, encryption of the home directory and relevant folders, protection against viruses etc. This would not be a task for the IDE. I also do not know what VisualStudio does exactly. Just not displaying the (otherwise accessible) local working copy would not serve anything.

Comment: Oh ok, so for managing CAS locally, i need to apply using Windows OS  built in secure functionality (Im using Windows 7), am I understood right?. Thank you for your reply..

Comment: If you want to prevent access for strangers, yes. However I am confused about the term "Code Access Security" here. I only found [CAS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to be a concept from .Net for limiting what privileges are assigned to programs by more factors than the executing user (for example from which website they were downloaded). I don't see the connection to preventing access to source code in an IDE.

Comment: Again Im sorry for my english, i just used that word(CAS) to mean prevent access from others.... I worked on dotnet long back(three years back), at that time im not aware of this feature CAS. Sorry for confusing you. Now im working on Android. Here in the current working company they asked me to go through and run the WinPhone project before start work on the New Android project. When i opened that project in VS.net IDE its asked for valid credentials to enter. So i asked this question. Thank you so much for clearing my doubts and your patience to answer my questions.... :)